# Is there a .Net library similar to GNU readline?

Tags: c#, .net, readline

I'm considering writing a console application in C# and I want to incorporate history, completion and command line editing features something like GNU readline (but not necessarily as extensive as that!)

Is there an existing library for .net which provides this type of functionality? I guess one option would be to use interop services to call GNU readline. But is there a native option?

Comment: Have you considered a PowerShell snap-in? That's the most 'native' option in the .NET world I can think of right now.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but when you start thinking about enhancing the user experience with a UI this way, you really ought to start looking at Windows Forms.

Comment: Not sure I follow? Are you suggesting I write my app as a powershell snap-in? Won't that just give me PowerShell's standard command line editing (ie, basic Windows console features plus the fancy tab completion)? I'm after more than that (history search, word deletion, things like that).

Comment: nobugz - A GUI app is fine, but I still want to allow the user command-line style interaction and command line editing. Consider PowerShell vs PowerShell ISE. Personally I hate the ISE command line editing facilities, I prefer the console version but I'd like a little more (which I can't add because the console IO isn't customisable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to checkout Miguel de Icaza's [getline.cs](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Aug-26.html) (the link in the blog post is broken, the code can now be found [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/tools/csharp/getline.cs)). Depending on what features of readline you actually need, it might be enough for your purposes.

The nice thing is, that it is all contained in a single (hence getline.cs) file and MIT X11 licensed.

Using it is pretty easy.

If you want to give it try, just download the file and compile it:

```
C:\> csc.exe /d:DEMO getline.cs 
C:\> getline.exe
shell>
```

The `#ifdef DEMO` part also shows the basic REPL:

```
var le = new LineEditor("whatever");
string s;

while ((s = le.Edit("my prompt> ", "")) != null)
{
    // User input from command line / prompt now in "s".
}
```

Comment: I've tried the getline library from the CSharpRepl project, but has a limited support for the tab-completion. Also, the completion feature itself is quite difficult to implement.
Maybe just my limits...

Comment: But the link isn't broken o.o

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but still relevant since it appears in Google search results. It makes sense to mention the following:

https://github.com/tonerdo/readline is a good option nowadays. Quoting its README:

> ReadLine is a GNU Readline like library built in pure C#. It can serve as a drop in replacement for the inbuilt `Console.ReadLine()` and brings along with it some of the terminal goodness you get from unix shells, like command history navigation and tab auto completion.
>
> It is cross platform and runs anywhere .NET is supported, targeting netstandard1.3 means that it can be used with .NET Core as well as the full .NET Framework.

#### License

The project is licensed under the MIT license

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is even more relevant than the accepted one, IMO.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. I ended up using Miguel's library mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2756850/227779 myself.

Comment: Interesting , good to know! It would be great to know why tonerodo readline didn't work well for you? From my shallow understanding, the one you mentioned in your answer looks more advanced.

Comment: @Evgeniy, I think I got the feeling that it was unmaintained. Miguel's library was also nice in that it was "self-contained"; I could just copy it into my app and use it without external dependencies. More details in this thread in my app's repo: https://github.com/perlang-org/perlang/issues/182#issuecomment-1039498915

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I know of is [Mono-Readline](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mono-readline/).

It provides a .NET interface to the GNU Readline library - it's a bit raw though, only version 0.0.1, and I've only ever seen it run on the Mono runtime.

You should be careful with licensing too ... AFAIK anything that links the GNU Readline libraries is required to be released under the GPL.

Answer (score 2):

a project that aims to emulate most of the functions of RedLine is [Deveel ReadLine](http://code.google.com/p/deveel-readline/), but I have to say that it isn't maintained. Last time I used it it worked very well on both .NET and Mono, although there's a small bug when canceling a line that was automatically folded.