# Have you seen library for flexible working with terminal(Unix like)?

Tags: c#, unix, mono, terminal

Have you seen library for flexible working with terminal(Unix like)?
I want to implement autocompletion, history, help params in my console application same operations you can see in the Unix terminals.

C#, Mono library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, GNU Readline support for Mono, [Mono-Readline](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mono-readline/).
See also, [Is there a .Net library similar to GNU readline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024170/is-there-a-net-library-similar-to-gnu-readline)

Comment: Mono-Readline have poor API. I found another one way Mono.Terminal.Editor. I will take a look in this reference and wrote about this one.

Comment: ok, I used readline.cs from Mono(LineEditor class). Example of application you can see at http://github.com/oivoodoo/mono-clish/